# I'm trying to Normalise a vector but my code returns a fail?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Below is my code sample, trying to normalize my 3 point vector {5, 5, 5}
however it is printing "Normalise - Failed" when running, may someone explain why it isn't succeeding this to me so i may attempt to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Geometry.h"
#include <math.h>

void Normalise()
{
    TVector3 _krA;//vector / mag vector = answer x y z
    {
        _krA.m_fX = 5;
        _krA.m_fY = 5;
        _krA.m_fZ = 5;
    }
    TVector3 _rResultant;
    {
        _rResultant.m_fX = (_krA.m_fX * _krA.m_fX);
        _rResultant.m_fY = (_krA.m_fY * _krA.m_fY);
        _rResultant.m_fZ = (_krA.m_fZ * _krA.m_fZ);
    }
    float _fResultFinalMag = sqrt(_rResultant.m_fX + _rResultant.m_fY + _rResultant.m_fZ);

    float _fresultXMag = (_krA.m_fX / _fResultFinalMag);
    float _fresultYMag = (_krA.m_fY / _fResultFinalMag);
    float _fresultZMag = (_krA.m_fZ / _fResultFinalMag);

    float _fNormliseTestX = 0.577350;
    float _fNormliseTestY = 0.577350;
    float _fNormliseTestZ = 0.577350;

    if (_fNormliseTestX == _fresultXMag && _fNormliseTestY == _fresultYMag && _fNormliseTestZ == _fresultZMag)
    {
        std::cout << "Normalise - Success" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Normalise - Failed" << std::endl;
        std::cout << _fresultXMag << std::endl;
        std::cout << _fresultYMag << std::endl;
        std::cout << _fresultZMag << std::endl;
        std::cout << _fResultFinalMag << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want help with a compilation error, please specify the exact compilation error(s) you get.

Comment: it runs fine, its the fact i don't understand why the code is returning failed

Comment: btw, you probably don't want to [compare `float` values using `==`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith)

Comment: I recommend testing the result in a different way: Calculate the length of the normalized vector --> it should be approximately 1

Comment: Ill attempt that now and get back to you thanks

Comment: Even if float numbers were precise, your code would return false, because the exact value isnt `0.577350` but `0.577350269189625764509....`. You wrongly assumed that your program will do the same rounding as you did.

Answer (score 7):

The reason your code prints `"Failed"`, is because you're comparing `float` values exactly using `==`. Floating point data types don't generally store values exactly, but instead store them with a certain precision. Furthermore, they're subject to rounding errors, further compounded the more calculations you perform with the values.

Have a read through this C++ FAQ entry about ["Why doesn’t my floating-point comparison work?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith) for a good explanation.

One option you have, is to compare using an epsilon :

```
float epsilon = 0.0001; // or whatever accuracy you require
if (fabs(_fNormliseTestX - _fresultXMag) < epsilon) {
    // _fNormliseTestX and _fresultXMag are considered equal
}
```

Comment: Ah thank-you i searched up fabs, and modified my code and now i have a better understanding thanks for your time.